# Why mouse not working with this form (html)

Tags: html, css

**why mouse not working with form in this link**

The mouse does not work when you press any of the input boxes in the Form

When you press any input box it does not activate the field

You must use the keyboard and press the tab button to access the field

[rooney.soonlabs.com/contact.html](http://rooney.soonlabs.com/contact.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the function mobiletouch(). Remove the function and the form works

You can check if is mobile before run:

Something like:

```
function isMobile() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}

function mobiletouch() {
    var mobile = isMobile();
 if(mobile){
    $('body').swipe({
        swipe: function (event, direction){

            if (direction == 'up'){
                $('.next').trigger('click');
            }else if(direction == 'down'){
                $('.previous').trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });  
   }
}
```

Add style to change the form font color:

```
<style>
.contact-form textarea, .form-inp { color: #FFF }
</style>
```

Comment: Works well on mobile
But does not work when run on a computer

Comment: The name I have understood is wrong , 

Thanks The problem was solved after using this code

Answer (score 0):

In your assets.css stylesheet you're overriding the `touch-action` property with the value `manipulation`:

```
[role=button], a, area, button, input, label, select, summary, textarea {
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action), the manipulation value disables user interaction except for scrolling and zooming/pinching. Therefore, clicking on the input field won't do anything.

Since I can't see anything you'd need this for, your problem should be solved by removing the above CSS rules (or removing the input and textarea selectors from the CSS rules).

Note: After you removed the CSS rules, you'll be able to write in the input fields, but won't see anything since the text color currently defaults to black. Therefore, simply add an additional `color: #fff;` rule to the input selector.

Comment: When you remove this code
[role=button], a, area, button, input, label, select, summary, textarea {
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
From the assets.css file
The problem remains after removing the code

Comment: For me it does work after removing that CSS rule. Try to force-reload the page (Ctrl + F5) in order to reload the CSS after you've made the changes.

Comment: Yes, delete it and confirm it and press ctrl + f5